# z-index not working on full screen mode with HTML5 video

Tags: html, css, video, z-index

I have some problems with HTML5 video when I make a page not app working on mobile. I have put some text on the video as overly div. It works perfectly when the video runs in normal mode but it seems the z-index not working on the full-screen video. This problem has troubled me a long time, and I have searched on google, StackOverflow, and CSS-tricks, not finding the right answer.

**My code is here**

```js
(function($, d) {
  $.each(readyQ, function(i, f) {
    $(f)
  });
  $.each(bindReadyQ, function(i, f) {
    $(d).bind("ready", f)
  })
})(jQuery, document)
```

```css
.vcontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.vcontainer video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.voverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="footer-links">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="section-title text-justify">
          <div class="vcontainer responsive float-center" id="myvideo">
            <video width="100%" height="auto" controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="" data-setup='{}'>
<source src="video.mp4"/>
                        </video>

            <div class="voverlay">
              <p>
                <span class="float-right sm-12 badge badge-danger">Student Name Reg-212111</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you describe what ‘not working’ means here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should overwrite the video fullscreen function and handle fullscreen on the parent of the video tag and your text. then you can use myVideo id.

```
    function toggleFullscreen() {
    let elem = document.querySelector("video");
    let elem2 = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        elem2.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
            alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
        });
    } else {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }
}
```